# Returning new dataframe from column range (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have the following dataframe:

```
df1
       3        4       5         6   
0    NaN      NaN     Sea       NaN
1  light   medium   light    medium
2     26     41.5      15        14
3     32       40      18        29 
4     41       29      19        42
```

And I am trying to return a new dataframe where only the Sea column and onwards remains:

```
df1
        5        6   
0     Sea      NaN
1   light   medium
2      15       14
3      18       29 
4      19       42
```

I feel I am very close with my code:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if pd.Series.any(df.iloc[:,i].str.contains(pat="Sea")):
        xyz = df.columns[i] #This is the piece of code I am having trouble with
    df = df.loc[:,[xyz:??]]
```

Essentially I would like to return the column index of where the word 'Sea' is contained and then create a new dataframe from that index to the length of the dataframe. Hopefully that explanation makes sense, and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1: Get the column name:

```
In [542]: c = df[df == 'Sea'].any().argmax(); c
Out[542]: '5'
```

Step 2: Use `df.loc` to index:

```
In [544]: df.loc[:, c:]
Out[544]: 
       5       6
0    Sea     NaN
1  light  medium
2     15      14
3     18      29
4     19      42
```

If `df.loc[:, c:]` doesn't work, you may want to fall back on a more explicit version (thanks to piRSquared for the simplification):

```
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc(c):]
```

Comment: Actually you can just index with `df.loc[:, c:]`

Comment: Ahh this is nicer than my approach.

Comment: @maxymoo interestingly I get the error of TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> but it runs normally with the old code

Comment: @Mitch Thank you :)

Comment: @codeninja Interesting... pandas version issue maybe? I'm on 0.20

Comment: Maybe try df.astype(object).eq('Sea') and think of where I might have gotten that idea.

Comment: @coldspeed i'm also on 0.20.1.. peculiar. However your original solution worked beautifully for me! thank you fro that

Comment: @piRSquared haha I can think of a few sources of inspiration :)

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks! That's a much simpler alternative. I tend to jump through hoops more often than I need to... part of the learning process I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could write a little rudimentary function to do so.

```
 def match_cut(df, to_match):
     for col in df.columns:
         if df[col].str.match(to_match).any():
             return df.loc[:, col:]
     return pd.DataFrame()
```

With that being said, [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405814/returning-new-dataframe-from-column-range-pandas/45405856#45405856) should be preferred as it avoids column looping like this function.

---

```
>>> match_cut(df, 'Sea')
       5       6
0    Sea  np.nan
1  light  medium
2     15      14
3     18      29
4     19      42
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try thisby using `list` and  `index`

```
df2.ix[:,df2.ix[0,:].tolist().index('Sea'):]


Out[85]: 
       5       6
0    Sea     NaN
1  light  medium
2     15      14
3     18      29
4     19      42
```